# kubernetes (kubectl) port forwarding not working on mac for IBM MQ/Docker deployment

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-mq, kubectl

I am trying to deploy IBM MQ to my local MAC machine using an image hosted on docker hub repository. I am using docker edge version with Kubernetes support on it.

I am able to deploy the image successfully using kubernetes and also have the Queue Manager running fine inside the container. I am also able to ssh into the container and make sure all the MQ processes are running as expected.

But when I use port forwarding using the following kubectl command, it opens the port, but does not let me telnet to it using "IP or hostname" (even from the local machine). But when I use "localhost" to telnet it works fine.

While troubleshooting, I deployed the same image using docker commands instead of kubernetes and with docker deployment, the port forwarding works as expected. It lets me telnet using IP, hostname and localhost.

So, definitely its some issue with Kubernetes port forwarding. Can some one please let me know if I am missing anything here? Let me know if there is some additional information needed from my end.

I am new to kubernetes and docker, but pretty familiar with IBM MQ.

***Commands being used:***

**To create port forwarding rule using kubectl, checking netstat and connecting with telnet:**

---

```
HOSTNAME:Test2 an0s5v4$ sudo kubectl port-forward private-reg 1414:1414 &

[1] 3001


HOSTNAME:Test2 an0s5v4$ Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:1414 -> 1414
Forwarding from [::1]:1414 -> 1414

HOSTNAME:Test2 an0s5v4$ netstat -an |grep 1414
tcp6       0      0  ::1.1414               *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.1414         *.*                    LISTEN  

HOSTNAME:Test2 an0s5v4$ ps -ef|grep 1414
    0  3001   920   0 10:27AM ttys006    0:00.03 sudo kubectl port-forward private-reg 1414:1414

    0  3002  3001   0 10:27AM ttys006    0:00.18 kubectl port-forward private-reg 1414:1414
  502  3007   920   0 10:28AM ttys006    0:00.00 grep 1414
```

---

```
HOSTNAME:Test2 an0s5v4$ telnet IP 1414

Trying IP...

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

---

```
HOSTNAME:Test2 an0s5v4$ telnet localhost 1414

Trying ::1...

Connected to localhost.

Escape character is '^]'.

Handling connection for 1414
```

---

```
L-RCC9048942:Test2 an0s5v4$ telnet HOSTNAME 1414

Trying IP ...

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

---

```
HOSTNAME:Test2 an0s5v4$ nslookup HOSTNAME

;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

Name:   HOSTNAME
Address: IP
```

---

**Kubernetes pod YAML file contents**

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Pod

metadata: 

  name: private-reg

  labels:

     app: ibmmq

spec: 

  containers: 

    - 

      env: 

        - 

          name: LICENSE

          value: accept

        - 

          name: MQ_QMGR_NAME

          value: QM4

      image: "image path in docker hub"

      name: private-reg-container

      ports: 

        - 

          containerPort: 1414

          hostPort: 1414
```

---

**EDIT: ADDED K8S Service to the post**

**Kubernetes service YAML file contents**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice-nodeport
  labels:
    app: ibmmq
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000 
    targetPort: 1414
    nodePort: 31414
  selector:
    app: ibmmq
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Anurag I don't know much about kubectl, but in reviewing some documentation you might want to try `sudo kubectl port-forward my-pod 1414:1414`

Comment: @JoshMc - Thanks for looking into it. Yes, I have tried sudo as well. But no luck so far :)

Comment: Anurag I changed `private-reg` to the literal value `my-pod`, have you tried that?

Comment: @JoshMN - I just tried that too. Same results ....

Comment: I have also tried with my YAML file modified from just pod to having a service point to the pod and try port forwarding on the service instead of pod. Have not worked so far.

Comment: The following blog post indicates you need to "make sure nsenter and socat are installed". https://prefetch.net/blog/2018/02/03/how-the-kubectl-port-forward-command-works/

Comment: @JoshMc - I have socat installed on my machine, but nsenter does not looks like installed. Let me try installing it and try again. Will get back.

Comment: @Anurag, have you created a Service to your Pod in Kubernetes? If the answer is yes, could you share its configuration?

Comment: @JoshMc - I got this fixed. I will mention the fix in the next comment. I did not had to install nsenter. May be it is already installed with Kubernetes/docker package.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev - Hey, thanks for taking a look at this thread. Yes, it got fixed after I created a service and associated it with the pod. The port external is handled in the service and pointed to the port in the pod.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Can you write up your solution as an answer for Anurag to accept, or if you or someone else has answered this before it could be flagged as a duplicate of that post and that post upvoted.

Comment: @Anurag, could you share complete YAML files for the Pod and the Service? Looking on one posted in the question, it should not work. Commands `kubectl get pod <pod_name> -o yaml` and `kubectl get service <service_name> -o yaml` will help you with that.

Comment: @JoshMc, for now it is not clear what is wrong. Sure, I will post the answer after we will figure out what is wrong

Comment: @JoshMC - I have added the service description to the post. Just unable to format it well.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev - I have added the service description to the post. Thanks !

Comment: Anurag, to format as fixed width, you can either highlight the block of text and click the icon at the top of the editor that looks like `{}` or you can just space the text in four spaces.

Comment: @Anurag, could you provide the pod description in the same way as you have provided the service description, using command `kubectl get pod <pod_name> -o yaml`?

Answer (score 3):

If you need port forwarding to bind to all the network interfaces, you can give this option. This will be useful when working with servers in OpenShift etc where there are different local and floating IPs

> --address 0.0.0.0

Example

```
kubectl port-forward minio-64b7c649f9-9xf5x --address 0.0.0.0 7000:9000 --namespace minio
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an known issue with the kubectl port-forward command. It only connects to the localhost interface. See this PR: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/46517. I still am looking onto this same issue too. I see two work-arounds:

1. **socat** option: (need to install with `brew install socat`) https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43962#issuecomment-418305960, which I don't really like as I need another port to listen to than to forward
2. **pf** solution: https://superuser.com/questions/473039/pfctl-port-forwarding-in-mac-osx#521803, which I still can't get working.

I added to the `/etc/pf.conf` file rules like: 
`rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 10001 -> 127.0.0.1 port 10001`, where `en0` is my wifi interface:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 6c:96:cf:dd:98:e9 
    inet6 fe80::b0:4b17:388d:8a1b%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.12.82 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 192.168.15.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

I have a terminal with the kubectl port-forward: `kubectl port-forward mypod 10001:10001`, but there is not listener on the `*:10001` port (you can check with the command: `sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`)

If I fix it I will edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307122/1155185) Docker will bind forwarded port to 127.0.0.1 despite being explicitly asked otherwise with `--address 0.0.0.0`.
This issue can be solved with `socat`. Given a following setup:

- `WebServer` running on port 8080 in kubernetes cluster
- Docker image, where `kubectl port-forward` is run and exposes it to the outside at port 9876
- HostOS where a Web Browser is accessing the `WebServer` at `localhost:9876`

The code to tunnel the connection would consist of following pieces:

1. Dockerfile

   `RUN yum -y install socat`
2. Docker run command

   `docker run --publish 9876:9876 ...`
3. port forwarding and exposing

   `kubectl --namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE port-forward pod/YOUR_POD_NAME --address 0.0.0.0 9877:8000 & socat TCP-LISTEN:9876,fork TCP:localhost:9877`

Here, port `9877` is used as a "jump port" to bypass Docker limitations.